# Access client IP from handler

Tags: python, socketserver

i'm wondering, can I access the address of the client from a  SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler (or more specifically, a subclass)? I didn't see any documentation on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [**`RequestHandler.handle()`**](http://devdocs.io/python/library/socketserver#socketserver.RequestHandler.handle):

> This function must do all the work required to service a request. The
>   default implementation does nothing. Several instance attributes are
>   available to it; the request is available as `self.request`; **the
>   client address as `self.client_address`**; and the server instance as
>   `self.server`, in case it needs access to per-server information.

Comment: Yeah, I subclassed and implemented a handle() method. I guess I somehow missed the piece about self.client_address... Thanks!